# HashMap Implementation (dictionary) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash-map, hashcode

I attempted making a hashmap in python, and it was harder, due to some limitations but this is my version of dictionaries in python. Are there any way to simplify or do the same thing in less code along with tips and tricks?

```
class HashMap:
    def __init__(self, memory): # refers to the length of the bucket
            self.data = [None] * memory 
            self.memory = memory

    def _hash(self, key):
        hashed_value = 0
        bucket_length = self.memory
        string_length = len(key)
        i = 0
        while i < string_length:
            hashed_value += (ord(key[i]) * i) % bucket_length
            if hashed_value > bucket_length-1:
                hashed_value %= bucket_length-1

            i += 1
        return hashed_value

    def set(self, key, value):
        address = self._hash(key)
        bucket = self.data[address]
        if not bucket:
            self.data[address] = [key, value, None] # None refers to next pointer
        else:
            while bucket[2] != None:
                bucket = bucket[2]
            bucket[2] = [key, value, None]

    def get(self, key):
        address = self._hash(key)
        bucket = self.data[address]
        if bucket:
            while bucket[2] != None or key != bucket[0]:
                bucket = bucket[2]
            if bucket:
                return bucket[1]
        raise KeyError

    def keys(self):
        keys_list = []
        bucket_list = self.data
        for bucket in bucket_list:
            current_bucket = bucket
            if bucket:
                while current_bucket != None:
                    keys_list.append(current_bucket[0])
                    current_bucket = current_bucket[2]
        return keys_list
```

Comment: I'm missing a description of how the hash function **should** work. `%` with anything other than the size is usually wrong. And `> bucket_length - 1`? What about `>= bucket_length`? What's so special about `bucket[2]`?

Comment: bucket[2] is like a pointer from a linked list, for example when creating a new key value pair a bucket will be [key, value, None] but when collisions happen it will be [key, value, [key2, value2, None] ]

Comment: and the modulo operator is for making sure, that the index we get from the hash function is a possible index for the bucket array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation of `get` is wrong. The code is:

```
def get(self, key):
        address = self._hash(key)
        bucket = self.data[address]
        if bucket:
            while bucket[2] != None or key != bucket[0]:
                bucket = bucket[2]
            if bucket:
                return bucket[1]
        raise KeyError
```

The line `while bucket[2] != None or key != bucket[0]` says "keep traversing the link list as long as it's possible to do so, and if it's impossible, try to do it anyway if the key is wrong". Because of the boolean `or`, the condition `bucket[2] != None` means the loop will always step forward in the linked list if it's possible to do so - *even if the current key is correct*. On top of that, once the loop gets to the last element, if the key at that position does not match the given key, the loop will attempt to iterate once more, giving us:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-a5939dc0e83e> in <module>()
----> 1 h.get("apple")

<ipython-input-1-4777e6d3506b> in get(self, key)
     31         bucket = self.data[address]
     32         if bucket:
---> 33             while bucket[2] != None or key != bucket[0]:
     34                 bucket = bucket[2]
     35             if bucket:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

The result is `get` fails with this error in every case except when the requested key is the last one in its slot.

The correct condition is of course `while bucket[2] != None and key != bucket[0]`. We then need to check afterwards that we got out of the loop because we found the right key, not because we ran out of buckets, giving us the implementation:

```
def get(self, key):
        address = self._hash(key)
        bucket = self.data[address]
        if bucket:
            while bucket[2] != None and key != bucket[0]:
                bucket = bucket[2]
            if bucket[0] == key:
                return bucket[1]
        raise KeyError
```

Comment: ahhh, that is very true, i couldn't test for these conditions and just assumed it works based on my first testcases, since generating the same memory place by hash, seemed very hard

Comment: @MahdeenSky You can test it by setting the memory to 1 when you create the hashmap

Comment: oh ill keep it mind, ty for taking your time fixing a mistake of mine, when it doesn't work as expected, since people tend to report the thread and downvote it for not working, on the other hand, people like you are what this stackexchange needs!!

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation of `set` is also wrong. If you set the same key twice, the first value should be overwritten.  Instead, the new key-value pair is added to the end of the bucket list, so memory usage will increase, the `keys` method will return multiple copies of the same key.

Comment: basically i should add change the condition of while bucket != None to while bucket != None and key != bucket[0]

Comment: ... followed by doing different things depending on whether or not `key` was found.  If you simply changed the condition, you'd lose any subsequent key-value pairs that were added to that `bucket` after that `key`.

Comment: oh a rather good point, so i basically only change the None if it loops through the whole keys in the memory, and change the value only if it isn't the above

Comment: Once you've fixed your code, you should [post a follow-up question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) with the updated code, complete with test cases you've used test the new implementation.  There is much more that can be improved in your implementation, but with an accepted answer, it is unlikely you will not garner any more feedback on this question.